# Getting error : [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, server-side-rendering

I have been getting this error even after trying all the solutions I could find on the internet.
I have tried to use computed property and also returning local variables rather than state, still it was of no use.
Here is my code:

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div class="timeline">
      <div v-for="story in storyText" :key="story" :class="bubbleDirection()">
        <div class="storyBubble">
          <storyBubble
            :story-line="story"
            :random-color="randomColor()"
            :data-aos="transition()"                                                                                             
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Methods in script:

```
data() {
    return {
      random: '',
      showSpinner: false,
      direction: 'container right',
      transitionDir: 'fade-left',...
```

methods:

```
{
    randomColor() {
      let colorArray = [...this.bubbleColor]
      colorArray = colorArray.filter((color) => this.random !== color)
      const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * colorArray.length)
      this.random = colorArray[rand]
      return this.random
    },
    bubbleDirection() {
      if (this.direction === 'container right')
        this.direction = 'container left'
      else this.direction = 'container right'
      return this.direction
    },
    transition() {
      if (this.transitionDir === 'fade-left') this.transitionDir = 'fade-right'
      else this.transitionDir = 'fade-left'
      return this.transitionDir
    },
  },}
```

The storyText here is an array of strings.

Comment: debug hint: put a `console.log` in each of those methods - see if any seem to get called a lot

Comment: @Bravo all the three methods mentioned above get called a lot of times than it should but I am not able to find an alternate to apply my function without using the method.

Comment: see, because your changing the value where you're getting the value, so, the value changes just as the value is retrieved, so the value is changed, so the value is retrieved, so ...

Comment: Thanks I get it :)